# ffmpeg batch process issue mac

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to batch process all files(with names containing spaces) in a directory. The script is like:

```
echo my converter
read -p "Enter give folder: " folder
echo '//////////////////////START CONVERTING FROM FOLDER///////////////////////'

find $folder -type f -name "*[[:space:]]*" | while read file; do
    release="${file%%.*}"'_t.mp4';
    echo "$file";
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -c copy "$release" -loglevel error -stats
    echo $release;
done
```

the script searches all the files in the address and ffmpeg one by one. However the first file will always fail due to some unknown issues:

```
[mpegts @ 0x7fb8e9904a40] Continuity check failed for pid 17 expected 2 got 3
[mpegts @ 0x7fb8e9904a40] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 0 got 2
[mpegts @ 0x7fb8e9904a40] Continuity check failed for pid 4096 expected 0 got 2
[mpegts @ 0x7fb8e9904a40] Continuity check failed for pid 256 expected 2 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x7fb8e9904a40] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 203523000).
/Users/xy/Downloads/aaa/aa vv.ts: corrupt input packet in stream 0
[NULL @ 0x7fb8e9905a40] Decoding VUI
```

If there is only one file, the process works fine.
If comment out the ffmpeg command, it echoes as expected:

```
/Users/xy/Downloads/aaa/aa vv_t.mp4
/Users/xy/Downloads/aaa/aa vv_t_t.mp4
/Users/xy/Downloads/aaa/aa vv.ts
/Users/xy/Downloads/aaa/aa vv_t.mp4
/Users/xy/Downloads/aaa/cc ee.ts
/Users/xy/Downloads/aaa/cc ee_t.mp4
```

it first find the target files and then converts into another with different file names.
Any suggestions, thank you!!

Comment: [I see](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11304232/e-e) you've never accepted an answer to any of your questions - please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do to thank people for answering, encourage future answers and increase your reputation so you can access more functionality on the site.

Comment: Always use shellcheck.net for syntax validation. It will help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this as a starting point at least:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo 'my converter'
read -p 'Enter give folder: ' folder
echo '//////////////////////START CONVERTING FROM FOLDER///////////////////////'

while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
    release="${file%%.*}_t.mp4"
    echo "$file"
    ffmpeg -nostdin -i "$file" -c copy "$release" -loglevel error -stats
    echo "$release"
done < <( find "$folder" -type f -name '*[[:space:]]*' -print0 )
```

As the bash tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at http://shellcheck.net before posting them here.". I expect shellcheck would have warned you about most of the issues I've corrected above.

See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089 for more info on the `ffmpeg` change I made. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

By the way, "folder" is Windows terminology, in Unix it's a "directory".